# How to check if a string contains multiple characters in Swift 5

Tags: swift, swift5

I have a failure initializer that takes a string, if this string contains incorrect characters (T, A, C, G) I want to return nil:

I tried something like this, unsuccessful:

```
init?(strand: String) {
    let success = strand.contains(where:  { !"TACG".contains($0) })
    if !success {
        return nil
    }

    self.strand = strand
}
```

I somehow got confused by the two `contains` calls, so I am not sure if my check is correct.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case I'd prefer the API `rangeOfCharacter(from` which checks the string against a character set

```
init?(strand: String) {
    guard strand.rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "TACG")) == nil else { return nil }
    self.strand = strand
}
```

Comment: recommend this one better than my answer, much cleaner

Comment: I don't see CharacterSet available anymore in Swift :/

Comment: It belongs to the Foundation framework: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/characterset

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to import Foundation you can also use Collection method allSatisfy

```
func allSatisfy(_ predicate: (Character) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Bool
```

And make sure your string contains all characters

```
let allSatisfy = "CGAT".allSatisfy("TACG".contains)
print(allSatisfy)  // true
```

Answer (score 1):

Just move the `!` placement, check out the code below .

```
 init?(strand: String) {
    let success = !strand.contains(where:  { "TACG".contains($0) }) 
    if !success {
        return nil
    }
    self.strand = strand
}
```